# How to get +25 in bounty?

Tags: discussion

I've noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407285/1525840) marked as +25 on bounty. How's that possible? When I bounty someone, I have to spit out at least 50. And I'm thrifty so I rarely do...

Comment: That doesn't help the thriftiness problem, @yellow. :-) Bounties have a minimum price of 50 reputation. The person who places the bounty has to pay the full price, even if only half (or none) of it is rewarded.

Comment: @CodyGray Probably wise. Otherwise, thrifty users might post a huge bounty to attract attention and then not award it to get some of the bounty back. I wouldn't do that, obviously, but others might be prone to "forget" to assign the amount.

Comment: You don't bounty "someone", you only pay for the advertising.  You are at 10.1 milliJons right now, that 9K rep isn't much good for anything else so you might as well invest it.  If the question is decent then the extra views can easily get it 10 votes or more.

Comment: @HansPassant Not sure what you refer to by *10 milliJons*. Is it something new or just a typo? Also, that 9K I have now is in fact good for something. At 10K one gets to do some other stuff and that's what I'm aiming for. Quintuple digits.